# Any other way to load a COM, besides Type.GetTypeFromProgID?

Tags: c#, dll, com, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an old DLL that is registered. I'm upgrading a website to .NET Core, and it must use the `netcoreapp1.0` framework.

Unfortunately, that means `Type.GetTypeFromProgID` is no longer supported. Is there any other way I can load this COM dll and invoke its methods?

The code does work if I use the `net461` framework, but I'm not allowed to use it.

**project.json**

```js
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {}
}
```

**Code:**

```
        //GetTypeFromProgID does not exist anymore
        var comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ABCCrypto2.Crypto");

        var abc = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);

        var license = _config["AbcCrypto:License"];
        var password = _config["AbcCrypto:Password"];

        comType.InvokeMember("License", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, abc, new object[] { license });
        comType.InvokeMember("Password", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, abc, new object[] { password });

        var hashed = comType.InvokeMember("Encrypt", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, abc, new object[] { data });

        return hashed.ToString();
```

I've tried this:

```
Assembly SampleAssembly;
SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Users\john-luke.laue\repositories\MyApp\src\ew\_dlls\ABCCrypto2\" + "ABCCrypto2.dll");
```

but I get an error:

> An unhandled exception has occurred: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\john-luke.laue\repositories\EspritWeb\src\ew_dlls\ABCCrypto2\ABCCrypto2.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: Why do you want to move to .Net Core? If you need to use a COM DLL, that means your program won't be able to run cross-platform anyway.

Comment: I inherited this app and it was written in .NET Core RC2 and used dnx. 
@svick Things were broken so I was forced to upgrade to RTM and dotnet core. 

I need to be able to deploy my app as a Portable/Framework Dependent application. (After publish, I need a DLL not an EXE).

Comment: If it uses dnx and also a COM DLL, then I think it means it uses e.g. `dnx461`, which is the equivalent of `net461`. Why are you not allowed to use that?

Comment: I need to publish the app as portable (framework dependent)  
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/

When I use net461, it does a self-contained deployment

Comment: `net461` can't possibly be self-contained. You can't include .Net Framework with your application.

Comment: So I have to use **netcoreapp1.0** if I want a portable deployment (DLL)?